# How would I get a GeForce 9500 GT to pass audio via DVI to an HDMI display?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a GeForce 9500 GT and the latest Nvidia drivers. It has 2 DVI ports. One is connected to a normal monitor, the other is connected to a HDTV, connected via a really long DVI-to-HDMI cable

The video displays fine on the TV but the audio isn't being passed.  I went to the Nvidia settings and see this:
[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

It is recognizing the TV, however when I click `Open Windows Sound settings...`, I see this:
[image: Sound control panel]

Even with all the disabled and hidden devices showing, it doesn't show the Sony TV for audio output.  How can I get the GeForce card to pass audio to the TV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: [Does DVI to HDMI carry audio?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/301410-33-does-hdmi-carry-audio)

So the answer seems to be that you're assuming the DVI port can throughput audio, which might not be true. If your graphics card has an HDMI port, use that. If not, get a card that does.

If you have a sound system, you can just output the sound from the computer directly to that and let the DVI run video only. It's a small hassle, but it's the way I do it at home (primarily to enable the feature where the sound disappears if I plug in my headphones to my computer).

**edit** The more I read about it, the more convinced I am your card does not support audio over HDMI. Looking at the [specs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9500-gt/specifications), HDMI is only listed under display, and you have nothing other than two DVI ports. The card is also a low-end GPU, so you wouldn't expect bells and whistles.

**edit2** If you have a **DVI-D** connector, it **can** transform into HDMI and therefore carry audio. If you have a **DVI-I** connector, it **cannot**.

[image]

Comment: oh wow such a simple reason why it doesn't work and I'm going stupid over it. I don't know why I didn't realize DVI doesn't carry audio sooner. Thanks

Comment: My system (https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/EN210_SILENTDI1GD3V2LP/) has a DVI port and another HDMI. It DOES carry audio through DVI (currently using a DVI to HDMI converter cable) all-right.

Comment: @Meetai.com you're right, DVI-D can output HDMI (including audio), other forms of DVI cannot. The 9500 GT seems to have a DVI-I connector. [1][2] so it does not support audio. [1] http://www.ixbt.com/video3/images/g92-9/ecs-9500gt-front.jpg [2] https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/DVI_Connector_Types.svg/181px-DVI_Connector_Types.svg.png

Answer (score -1):

Actually DVI-I does support audio. This has nothing do with DVI it all depends on if your card has audio like my card it has an HDMI port but I've used DVI to HDMI adapter in the past because I didn't have a mini hdmi to HDMI adapter but I had a DVI to HDMI adapter so I used it. If your card has HDMI on it then yes you can get audio through dvi to hdmi adapter but if it doesn't then no sorry you can't

Comment: As per Wikipedia: "Some DVI-D sources use non-standard extensions to output HDMI signals including audio (...) Exact capabilities vary by video card specifications." -- please source your claim that DVI-I supports transferring audio to HDMI.